# How to change EBS volume type on a running instance with Boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, boto3

AWS supports modifying a mounted EBS volume's type (magnetic, SSD, etc) by both console and CLI ([docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-expand-volume.html)).  But the [volume class](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#volume) in Boto3 doesn't seem to support an action that [modifies volume attributes](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Volume.modify_attribute) other than AutoEnableIO and DryRun.

Is there a way to change EBS volume type with Boto3 that I am not seeing or piecing together from the documentation?

Comment: I doubt if you can modify the volume attributes of a running instance.

Comment: @helloV oh, yes.  It's a new thing. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-ebs-update-new-elastic-volumes-change-everything/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`modify_volume()`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.modify_volume) method:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ec2')
response = client.modify_volume(VolumeId='vol-xxxxxxxx',VolumeType='io1',Iops=100)
```

Works fine, even on a running boot volume.

Comment: Perfect!  Worked for me too.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The best option for you to solve this would be:

1. Take a snapshot of your volume
2. create a new volume using that snapshot
3. while creating new volume change the desired type
4. Detach the original drive and then attach the newly created drive

But the drawback is you have to restart your VM , you cant perform the whole procedure without restarting the VM .

```
new_volume_id=$(aws ec2 create-volume \
  --region "$region" \
  --availability-zone "$zone" \
  --size "$size" \
  --snapshot "$snapshot_id" \
  --output text \
  --volume-type <value>
  --query 'VolumeId')
```

Once new volume created , you can attach the new volume. but before that you have to stop your instance:

```
    aws ec2 attach-volume \
  --region "$region" \
  --instance "$instance_id" \
  --device "$root_device" \
  --volume-id "$new_volume_id"
```

I am not sure whether this answer would help you in this case.

Hope it will help at some extent !

Comment: None of this is necessary, most of the time, any more.  In 2017, EBS began to support hot modification of live volumes.  You can change the volume size (increase only) as well as the storage type, and EBS handles the migration transparently, live.  The kernel gets notice of the volume capacity change, and you can resize the volume's filesystems.  If the instance is older, it may not support it, in which case you do have to stop the instance and detach the volume, but you can then modify the volume and reattach it.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-expand-volume.html